# Unable to stop and rm docker containers from Scala script

Tags: scala, docker, process, ammonite

I am trying to execute the following command from within an ammonite Scala script:

```
 Process("docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)")
```

I always get the following output:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker stop --help'.
```

I've tried so many different variations without any luck, however it works fine from the console. Some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a string to `Process` then scala will just split it on spaces, and it won't be clever enough to interpret things like bash's command substitution `$()`.

The easiest workaround would be to use a `Seq` of commands, and wrap your stuff in a call to bash:

```
Process(Seq("bash", "-c", "docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)"))
```